# Paramiko: "not a valid RSA private key file"

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am trying connect to server using following spinet

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ip = ['x.x.x.x']
key_file = "/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa"

key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(key_file)
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.connect(ips, port=22, username='XYZ', pkey=key, timeout=11)
```

But I am getting an error:

> not a valid RSA private key file

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I faced a similar situation and ssh-keygen comes to my help. You should make a copy of id_rsa and convert it to RSA type with ssh-keygen.

To Convert *"BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY"* to *"BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY"*

```
ssh-keygen -p -m PEM -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: Paramiko now supports the new OpenSSH format. The conversion is no longer needed. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54612609/850848#60000004).

Answer (score 20):

Recent versions of OpenSSH (7.8 and newer) generate keys in *new* OpenSSH format by default, which starts with:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

That format is fully supported by the Paramiko since [version 2.7.1 (2019-12-09)](https://www.paramiko.org/changelog.html#2.7.1) only.

---

If you are stuck with an older version of Paramiko, you can use [`ssh-keygen`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen) to convert the key to the *classic* OpenSSH format:

```
ssh-keygen -p -f file -m pem -P passphrase -N passphrase
```

(if the key is not encrypted with a passphrase, use `""` instead of `passphrase`)

For Windows users: Note that `ssh-keygen.exe` is now built-in in Windows 10. And can be [downloaded from Microsoft Win32-OpenSSH project](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH) for older versions of Windows.

---

On Windows, you can also use PuTTYgen (from [PuTTY package](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/)):

- Start PuTTYgen
- Load the key
- Go to *Conversions > Export OpenSSH key*.
  For RSA keys, it will use the *classic* format.

---

If you are creating a new key with `ssh-keygen`, just add [`-m PEM`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen#m) to generate the new key in the *classic* format:

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM
```

---

Note that you can get the error, also when you are trying to use a completely different key format, like ssh.com or PuTTY .ppk. Then you will have to convert the key in any case.

- For ssh.com format, see [Paramiko: "not a valid DSA private key file"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70801012/850848).
- For PuTTY .ppk format, use PuTTYgen as shown above.

Answer (score 4):

The `paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file` method requires the private key file to be in "PEM" format.  Examine the file you're trying to read and see if it begins with a line that says:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

If it doesn't have that line then it's not PEM.

If it's not PEM then you'll have to find some way to create a PEM version of the private key.  (**EDIT**: the original poster used PuTTY's `puttygen` utility to export the private key into a PEM-format file.)

Make sure that the new file has the same ownership and limited access permissions that the original `id_rsa` file has, so that nobody can steal the key by reading the file.  Then, obviously, modify your `paramiko` call to read the key from the new PEM-format file.

Comment: The command you shared only generated public key again no private RSA. i used some other tutorial for linux ssh-keygen but it doesnt works only thing works with putty keygen with windows.
just export the private key with GUI and use it.

Comment: That's so weird.  I'll chop that whole translation part out of my answer in case it misleads anyone else.  The important thing is that you have to end up with the private key in PEM format.  I'm glad you were able to get there by using PuTTY.

Comment: Paramiko now supports the new OpenSSH format. The conversion is no longer needed. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54612609/850848#60000004).

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same error while I was connected with ssh to an Ubuntu VM.
In my terminal `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable is not defined, and paramiko throws the `not a valid RSA private key file` error.
However, if I am connected in a graphical session to the same machine, the graphical terminal has got `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` defined, and Paramiko is happy.
As a workaround, I have copied the content of `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in my SSH terminal and it works better.

Comment: But that means that Paramiko uses a key from authentication agent, rather then the key from the file. So your code probably does not do what you wanted.

Comment: You are right, by default paramiko gets the key from the authentication agent. If it cannot, it defaults to `~/.ssh/id.rsa` which was not in PEM format and @ahirapara answer fixes it.

Comment: Or you can (should) upgrade Paramiko to the latest version, which supports the `OPENSSH` format, as [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54612609/850848#60000004) says.

Comment: That's true but I currently use ubuntu's system version of python, afaik I cannot upgrade paramiko version

Comment: It is installed with `apt install python3-paramiko`. In the past I have installed newest version of some python packages with pip and broken my linux distribution. Of course I could use pyenv or something...

Answer (score 0):

As I checked, there was no issue with the path as well permissions(only read permission on the RSA file will work), so the problem was with the Paramiko version.
I updated it using the below command and it resolved the issue for me.

```
pip3 install paramiko update
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me:

- install the `putty` package:

```bash
brew install putty
```

- convert the .ppk into .pem :

```bash
puttygen <filename>.ppk -O private-openssh -o <filename>.pem
```

- give a try one more time through python paramiko:

```py
import paramiko

username, hostname, port = ('username', 'domain.com', 22,)
transport = paramiko.Transport(hostname, port)
private_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(open(pem_file_path))
params = {"username": username, "pkey": private_key}
# if there is a password, add it to the previous dict
transport.connect(**params)
conn = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
```

Some good references:

- https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-ppk-pem-conversion/