# How to load openssh private key using cryptography python module?

Tags: cryptography, python

I am getting ValueError("Could not deserialize key data.") if I use load_pem_private_key from from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization

To add more context:

My key starts with

`-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----`

The code segment that raises this Error

```
key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(data=private_key.encode(),
                                         password=None,
                                         backend=default_backend())
```

The traceback of the error shows

> backend=default_backend()) ->     return
> backend.load_pem_private_key(data, password) in load_pem_private_key
> ->     password, in load_pem_private_key
> -> self._handle_key_loading_error() in _load_key

Answer (score 3):

As of cryptography version 3.0 (released [2020-07-20](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/changelog/?highlight=load_ssh_private_key#v3-0)), you can now use the [`load_ssh_private_key()` function](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.load_ssh_private_key) to load SSH private keys that are stored in the `OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY` PEM format:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f demo_keypair -N 'example-passphrase' -C ''
$ python -c '
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_ssh_private_key
from hashlib import sha1
key = load_ssh_private_key(open("demo_keypair", "rb").read(), b"example-passphrase")
print(sha1(key.sign(b"demo data")).hexdigest())
'
df551fcad0a0e288f0f92ca9e4876eb57a483c27
```

Note that to load a *passphrase protected* key you must have the [`bcrypt` module](https://pypi.org/project/bcrypt/) installed (version 3.1.5 or newer); the documentation unfortunately doesn't make this explicit, but the error message you get if `bcrypt` is not installed is reasonably clear:

```
cryptography.exceptions.UnsupportedAlgorithm: Need bcrypt module
```

You can use the `ssh` extra to pull in `bcrypt` as a dependency:

```
pip install cryptography[ssh]
```

Answer (score 1):

pyca/cryptography mostly uses OpenSSL, and [*for private key* supports mostly the formats OpenSSL supports](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/#serialization-formats) which does not include OpenSSH's 'new' format. It does however add the OpenSSH *public key* format, so it might not be absurd to ask them about adding OpenSSH private. In the interim ...

Given you have OpenSSH, you can use `ssh-keygen` to convert the OpenSSH 'new' format back to OpenSSH's 'old' format which is OpenSSL's 'traditional' or 'legacy' format, by claiming you want to change the password -- even if you make the new password the same as the old password, or since you apparently want an unencrypted file, make the new password empty just as did the old password:

```
# OpenSSH 7.8 up 
ssh-keygen -f keyfile -p -m pem 
# below 7.8 
ssh-keygen -f keyfile -p # NOT -o
```

Or if you have PuTTY 0.69 up, puttygen can also do this, although the UI varies between Windows and Unix.

Dupes:
[SSH key generated by ssh-keygen is not recognized by Paramiko: "not a valid RSA private key file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53600581/ssh-key-generated-by-ssh-keygen-is-not-recognized-by-paramiko-) (Paramiko is SSH in Python)
["Invalid privatekey" when using JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53134212/invalid-privatekey-when-using-jgit-and-jsch) (Java, but same issue)